# unable to install hbase on windows

Tags: windows, hbase

I am trying to  install hbase 0.94.13. I modified the hbase-default.xml so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section xml:id="hbase_default_configurations" version="5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"><title>HBase Default Configuration</title><para/><glossary xml:id="hbase.default.configuration"><title>HBase Default Configuration</title><para>
The documentation below is generated using the default hbase configuration file,
<filename>hbase-default.xml</filename>, as source.
</para><glossentry id="hbase.rootdir"><glossterm><varname>hbase.rootdir</varname></glossterm><glossdef><para>The directory shared by region servers and into
    which HBase persists.  The URL should be 'fully-qualified'
    to include the filesystem scheme.  For example, to specify the
    HDFS directory '/hbase' where the HDFS instance's namenode is
    running at namenode.example.org on port 9000, set this value to:
    hdfs://namenode.example.org:9000/hbase.  By default HBase writes
    into /tmp.  Change this configuration else all data will be lost
    on machine restart.
   ....</glossary></section>
```

I followed this tutorial  http://ics.upjs.sk/~novotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows  but got this error:

```
19/02/17 17:59:37 FATAL conf.Configuration: bad conf file: top-level element not <configuration>
19/02/17 17:59:37 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
19/02/17 17:59:37 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
19/02/17 17:59:37 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (null), this version is 0.94.13
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool.main(HBaseConfTool.java:38)
19/02/17 17:59:38 FATAL conf.Configuration: bad conf file: top-level element not <configuration>
19/02/17 17:59:38 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
19/02/17 17:59:38 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
19/02/17 17:59:38 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (null), this version is 0.94.13
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool.main(ZKServerTool.java:39)
starting master, logging to /cygdrive/c/hbase-0.94.13/bin/../logs/hbase-user-master-user-PC.out
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
user@localhost's password:
localhost: regionserver running as process 9820. Stop it first.
```

can you please help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems, Zookeeper jar is missing from HBASE_CLASSPATH.  You need to set it in `hbase-env.sh` file.

```
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=<Path to the Zookeeper jar and other depenedencies>
```

Comment: export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/hbase-2.1.3-bin/lib/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar this is what i added in hbase-env.sh and the error persists